# Extract ADF monitor data to blob using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can we copy adf activity monitor tab data into blob using adf copy and any other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage is moving to use Azure Monitor for logging.

You can follow this [article](https://azure.github.io/Storage/docs/application-and-user-data/basics/azure-storage-classic-logs-to-data-explorer/), where detailed steps are given on how to store metrics of data factory in Storage account.

Log format details are given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format), you can pick required configuration from given list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Diagnostic settings from the ADF monitoring section.
2. Add diagnostic settings.
3. Choose the desired logs from the left and select "Archive to a storage account" option from the right.
4. Everytime from now on, when the pipeline is executed, the monitoring logs will be stored in the blob storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Another route you could take is using the CLI to get the same stats. PowerShell cmdlets are ample for azure applications, and ADF has an extensive library. Then it's just a matter of converting the content.
Two in specific that could be of use:

- [Get-AzDataFactoryActivityWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryactivitywindow?view=azps-9.2.0)
- [Get-AzDataFactoryV2ActivityRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2activityrun?view=azps-9.2.0)

Hope I was of some help!